# Use of reset method when implementing Poolable interface

Tags: libgdx

What to put in a reset method in a Poolable interface? I really confused what code should I put in there.

Answer (score 0):

In the `reset` method you put code that will make sure the object in the pool is ready for re-use. The `reset` method is called when `Pool.free` is invoked and is used to guarantee that the object in the pool is in a known, safe state.

For example; if you, for some reason, had a pool of `IntMap<String>` (i.e. a map keyed on `int`s holding `String`s) you might want to call `clear` on the `IntMap<String>` in the `Poolable`s `reset` method to make sure that when someone gets a pooled map, it doesn't contain any items left behind by the last guy using that pooled instance.